# How is fluid pressure defined?

Tags: pressure, definition, fluid-statics

In general, the pressure $p$ due to force acting on a surface of area $A$ perpendicular to it is defined as 
$$p=F/A$$
assuming that the force is distributed uniformly over $A$. Otherwise, we can define it as $$\dfrac{dF}{dA}$$

However, I don't understand the term *fluid pressure.* My book defines it the following way: Suppose a piston of surface area $A$ is suspended in a fluid. Then, the fluid exerts some force on the piston, and it compresses. Then the ratio of $F$ and $A$ is defined as its pressure. The force is measured by the amount of compression of the piston. However, for different areas, the ratio $\dfrac{F_{\text {fluid}}}{A}$ is different. So, how can fluid pressure be defined uniquely?

Comment: "However, for different areas, the ratio $\frac {F_{fluid}} A$ is different. "  If they are experiencing the same pressure, that's not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that the piston is held at a level in the fluid, say some depth $z$ below the surface, then the pressure will be same on that level. Then you can uniquely define the pressure on the piston. If you want a more general description, you can assume piston to be infinitesimally small and then pressure will be defined locally at that point in the fluid.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure of a fluid column of density $\rho$ may be defined as the **force exerted** by the column of fluid due to its weight **per unit area** on the surface below it.

This may be regarded as a universal definition because the addition of *per unit area* relieves the definition of any constraints posed by the area of the lower surface.